# My registry key doesn't exist when query through my VB.NET application

Tags: c#, vb.net

When I check manually, I see below registry key in the reristry.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{44FA2BAA-3C54-41D2-9F24-D0EE0131C695}_is1

But when I query all subkeys in my VB.NET program, I don't see **{44FA2BAA-3C54-41D2-9F24-D0EE0131C695}_is1**. My application gives totally different Subkeys. Am I missing something? Here is the source code.

```
   Dim regKey As RegistryKey
    regKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
    For Each subKeyName As String In regKey.GetSubKeyNames()
        If subKeyName.Contains("44FA2BAA") Then
           ' CONTROL NEVER COMES HERE 

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: more there is a bug in your **code**, like maybe an unhandled access violation exception

Comment: Updated the question with source code.

Comment: Sure you are missing something.  You forgot to tell us that you are running the 64-bit version of Windows.  Reading the 32-bit registry keys is okay, just different.  Otherwise a good reminder that you should *never* monkey with the registry, dragons live there.  Use superuser.com to ask questions about it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, I am running 64-bit version of windows. Thanks. What change should I make in the code?

Comment: Don't make any changes, it works fine.  It is not "your" registry key, it belongs to a 64-bit program.  Don't mess with it.  If you want to visit Rome then you'll have to act like a Roman.  Lots of questions around already that describe how to run as a 64-bit process.